# Can I use ConcurrentHashMap with Integer for thread safe counters?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I want to have several counters, which I can address by name. So, I can implement it in this way:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new Integer(0));
map.computeIfPresent("key", (k, v) -> v + 1);
```

Is it code a thread safe?

I think so, because we have synchronized access because of `ConcurrentHashMap`, and set new reference is thread safe operation too. Other threads will see this changing because of safe publication, which occurs when we leave bucket lock in `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: You might as well use `AtomicInteger`. (Also, `Integer.valueOf`.)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline yea, I may use it. But I just wonder, may I use Integer for this purpose.

Comment: Those two seperate statements are thread safe, but together they are not because you have 2 calls and those 2 calls are not together atomic. if you want those 2 calls just use `compute` and handle both cases in the `BiFunction`. Also have a look at [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) method - this might also do what you require

Comment: @michalk hm, but I don't need atomicity for 2 operations. If many threads create counter, only one will have success.

Comment: you can safely replace `new Integer(0)` with `0` – autoboxing will take care of it for you

Comment: Note that `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();` is **NOT** thread-safe, assuming `map` is some persistent variable.  So depending on the context of how it's actually called, that might be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the first statement, `map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new Integer(0));` happens at "initialization time", then having a bunch of threads performing calls of the form `map.computeIfPresent("key", (k, v) -> v + 1);`, yes, the algorithm is going to be correct (did I understand well your intent?).

Recent versions of the JDK guarantee that calls to `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent()` will not only invoke the expression passed in in a thread-safe way, it will also guarantee that if other threads attempt to act on that very same key at the same time, they'll block and get queued, such that all mutations happen in sequence (this is called serializability in distributed-systems parlance).

Comment: What do you mean with “recent versions”? Is there any version where this is not guaranteed? Besides that, `map.merge(key, 1, (a,b) -> a+b)` or `map.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)` will work for both, initialization of an absent key and updating a present key.

Comment: @Holger: The behavior changed from JDK7 to JDK8, or from 8 to 9, I don't remember. If I'm not mistaken it used to always go through synchronization and now it will only do it if there's indeed some thread in the middle of a computation.

Comment: The method did not exist before Java 8 and that's the version which also defined the semantic we still have today. Further, your statements contradict each other. In the answer you say "Recent versions of the JDK ... will also guarantee..." which implies that this additional guaranty was not present in some version, whereas in the comment you say "it used to always go through synchronization", which would be a potential performance issue, but still provide all guarantees you mention.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's threadsafe, you can test:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ThreadsafeExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        int count = 1000;
        AtomicInteger doneTasks = new AtomicInteger();
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[count];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < threads.length ; ++i) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new Integer(0));
                map.computeIfPresent("key", (k, v) -> v + 1);
                doneTasks.incrementAndGet();
            });
        }
        for(int i = 0 ; i < threads.length ; ++i)
            threads[i].start();

        while (doneTasks.get() < count)
            Thread.sleep(3);

        System.out.println("we expected count of key is: " + count + ", and we get: " + map.get("key"));
    }

}
```

output:

```
we expected count of key is: 1000, and we get: 1000
```

You can replace:

```java
map.computeIfAbsent("key", k -> new Integer(0));
map.computeIfPresent("key", (k, v) -> v + 1);
```

by

```java
map.compute("key", (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);
```

Comment: Instead of `map.compute("key", (k, v) -> v == null ? 1 : v + 1);`, you can use `map.merge("key", 1, (a,b) -> a+b);` or `map.merge("key", 1, Integer::sum);`…